# Theme & Props in makeStyles with TS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, makestyles

Found lots of similar questions but nothing that quite answers this. How do you pass both `theme` and `props` to the Material UI `makeStyles` hook but access them from the outermost closure without TS exploding? Something like this:

```
type StyleProps = {
  post: Post;
}

const useStyles = makeStyles<Theme, StyleProps>((theme: Theme, props: StyleProps) => ({
    root: {
      maxWidth: '100%',
      backgroundImage: ({ post }) => post.mainImage
    },
    date: {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      marginLeft: theme.spacing(2)
    },
    heroimage: {
      maxWidth: '100%',
      height: 'auto',
      objectFit: 'cover'
    }
}))
```

TS Error:

```
Type '(theme: Theme, props: any) => { root: (props: any) => CSSProperties; expandable: (props: any) => CSSProperties; iconContainer: { position: string; top: number; right: number; display: string; }; expandMoreIcon: (props: any) => CSSProperties; bannerContent: (props: any) => CSSProperties; }' is not assignable to type 'StyleRulesCallback<Theme, StyleProps, string>'.
```

I can access props inline from a style block like you see in `root` but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: What `props` are you expecting to get?

Comment: The props you would get if you passed it to the function call: `const classes = useStyles({ post: { mainImage: '' } })` for example.

Comment: `that's not what I'm looking for` - are you looking for a way to get the props only once and then use it like `backgroundImage: `url(${post.mainImage})`?